# React Native Hook issue - Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-dom, react-dom-server

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import useFetch from './useFetch';

const BlogDetails = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { data: blog, error, isPending } = useFetch('http://localhost:3001/blogs/' + id);

    return (
        <div className="blog-details">
            { isPending && <div>...Loading...</div>}
            { error && <div>{error}</div>}
            { blog && (
                <article>
                    <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
                    <p>Written by {blog.author}</p>
                    <div>{blog.body}</div>
                </article>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default BlogDetails;
```

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {
        const [data, setData] = useState(null);
        const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortCont = new AbortController();

        fetch(url, { signal: abortCont.signal })
            .then(res => {
                if(!res.ok){
                    throw Error('404 - data not found!');
                } 
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                setData(data);
                setIsPending(false);
                setError(null);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
                    console.log('fetch aborted');
                } else {
                    setIsPending(false);
                    setError(err.message);
                }
            })

            return () => abortCont.abort();
    }, [url]);

    return {data, isPending, error}
}

export default useFetch;
```

I am fairly new to react and i have spent about 2 days searching, adding and removing packages on VSCode to no avail.

I am following the Net Ninja's recent tutorial on Youtube and I am stuck on step #25.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7VmF4WsLCo&t=4s)

I have copied the code exactly but the issue seems somewhere else in React.

If anyone could help or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

[This is the error that is giving each time I try to access the page. It is thrown for any of the pages that is not on the main page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGh2M.png)

Comment: Hi Caddle, You need to provide some more details to people help you out. Your error points to `useParams` hooks called at `BlogDetails`, thus you should consider adding these pieces of your code to your question. Use the tools to format it the code properly. Please, don't print and paste the code.

Comment: Apologize, i have added the BlogDetails page and the useFetch page. I am still getting my head around the understanding of Hooks and got lost googling answers for this issue.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the piece of code is fine. the error is triggered by `useParams` which is a stable hook from `react-dom`, and you are calling at a function component which is correct. I believe you are calling `BlogDetails` correctly also. it's more likely the error due to issues regarding installed react packages, like the error points out.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if that may be the issue. I was thinking of re-starting the project in a fresh file and re-installing the packages as needed if that would have any benefit.
All the versions seemed to be up to date but I will double-check later and re-deploy.
Thanks for your advice, very appreciated.